# Seeking Advice on Local AI Model for Analyzing Personal Files

Tags: models, language-model, filters

I'm embarking on a project to develop an application for personal use that can assist me in retrieving specific information from my files. I'd like to be able to ask questions like "What was my income last year?" and get accurate answers directly from my stored documents.
One of my primary concerns is privacy; I want to keep my data as secure as possible. Therefore, I am interested in utilizing a local AI model that doesn't rely on cloud-based services. As I am relatively new to the world of AI, I'm looking for suggestions on which models would be most suitable for my needs.
After some preliminary research, I've come across Langchain, which seems to fit my requirements well. However, I'm open to other suggestions too.
A potential complication is that my files are not in any specific format or structure; they range from PDFs and text files to PowerPoints and Excel spreadsheets. I can segregate them into separate folders if that would be helpful. My question is, would restructuring my files into a specific format improve the accuracy of the AI model giving me proper answer?
I'd appreciate any advice on the following:

1. What AI model would be best suited for my project?
2. Is Langchain a good choice for this type of task?
3. Would reformatting my files increase the model's accuracy?

My current hardware:

- RAM: DDR5 64GB
- GPU : 3090
- CPU: I9 11TH

Thank you for your time and expertise!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.